# How to change an existing field in the MongoDb schema

Tags: mongodb

I have a working base. How can I remove the attribute of uniqueness for one of the fields?

`connectId : {type : String, index: true, unique: true},`

I need to remove  `unique: true`

`connectId : {type : String, index: true},`

[image]

Thanks

Comment: you must recreate the index with unique:false

Comment: Thanks. Can you write a sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You would just need to use the $unset operator:

```
db.collection.update({},{$unset: {"connectId.unique": ""}});
```

Please find below more documentation on the $unset operator [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

Comment: It did not work for me. WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
db.connections.dropIndex("connectId_1")
db.connections.createIndex({connectId: 1}, {background: "true"})
```